# How to move characters in a bit string over one position to the left with wrapping?

Tags: python

I need to add to my current code a way to move the characters as shown in the example below one position to the left keeping space in-between.

Use the strategy of the decimal to binary conversion and the bit shift left operation defined in Project 5 to code a new encryption algorithm.

The algorithm should

Add 1 to each character’s numeric ASCII value.
Convert it to a bit string.
Shift the bits of this string one place to the left.
A single-space character in the encrypted string separates the resulting bit strings.

An example of the program input and output is shown below:

Enter a message: Hello world!

0010011 1001101 1011011 1011011 1100001 000011 1110001 1100001 1100111 1011011 1001011 000101

```
info = input("Enter: ")
code = ""
for i in info:
    i = ord(i)
    i += 1
    if i == 0:
        print(0)
    else:
        bstring = ""
        while i > 0:
            remainder = i % 2
            i = i // 2
            bstring += str(remainder)
    code += bstring
    code += " " 

print(code)
```

This is 2/3 of the battle.

Answer (score 0):

You probably finished your homework unless you've been working on it for the last 2.5 years, but I just did this exact problem for a class.  I used a recursive function first, but then went back to see how to do it with loops since we weren't supposed to know how to use recursion yet.

There is probably a smoother way to do the bit shift left operation, but this is the one I figured out first!  Here it is for posterity.

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
count = 0
characters = 0
temp = ""
while count < len(message):
    characters += int((ord(message[count]))+1) #adds 1 to each ASCII val.
    count += 1
    
    bitString = ""
    iterationCount = 0 #used below for parsing the new bit string
                       #with 1's added to shift the bit string digits left
    while characters > 0:
        # next few lines changes the new number to bit string
        remainder = characters % 2
        characters = characters // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString
        #the next variables are used below to create the new
        #shifted-left version of bitString
        iterationCount += 1
        shiftedString = ""
        bitStringParse=0
        
        #The loop below creates a new shifted-left string by starting at 
        #the second digit and making it first in order until the last digit 
        #which is still in the last place until the far left digit is added 
        #to the far right when it's printed at the end
        
        for iterations in range(iterationCount-1):
            shiftedString += bitString[bitStringParse+1]
            bitStringParse+=1
    print(shiftedString+bitString[0], end = " ")
    
    #I'm just adding the missing piece by adding bitString[0] which is 
    #putting the left most variable on the far right.
```